# Metatrader 4 not making webrequests properly on a linux server

Tags: c, linux, server, webrequest, metatrader4

I'm currently hosting metatrader 4 on a linux server where the trading bot on the metatrader 4 performs webrequests.
The same bot works fine on my own system and my friends system. But on the server it doesn't get anything from the webrequests.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPVz3.png)

**Environment Information:**

- Ubuntu Linux
- Server by Contabo Servers
- MT4 running via wine on linux

**Tried so far**

- I have enabled all webrequest options within the metatrader 4.
- I tried unblocking the port 443 using ufw but didn't get anything out of it.
- Tried these articles as well

  - [https://www.malibal.com/guides/how-to-open-ports-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want,need%20to%20open%20port%2022](https://www.malibal.com/guides/how-to-open-ports-on-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want,need%20to%20open%20port%2022)
  - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-open-allow-incoming-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish
    https://contabo.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-software-firewall-in-linux-and-windows/
  - [https://www.malibal.com/guides/how-to-open-ports-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want,need%20to%20open%20port%2022](https://www.malibal.com/guides/how-to-open-ports-on-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want,need%20to%20open%20port%2022)

The following is the webrequest code which runs fine on all my personal systems but unfortunately not on contabo servers:

```
int InternetGetFile(string url,string &content)
  {
//--- Init
   content=NULL;

//--- Create connection
   int httpconnect=0;
   int httprequest=0;
   int httpopen=Wininet::InternetOpenW("InternetGetFileMQL",0," "," ",0);
   int e=kernel32::GetLastError();
   if(e==0)
     {
      bool flag=Wininet::DeleteUrlCacheEntryW(url);
      httprequest=Wininet::InternetOpenUrlW(httpopen,url,NULL,0,16|10,0);
      e=kernel32::GetLastError();
      if(e==0)
        {
         //--- Define buffers
         uchar ch[512];
         string temp="";

         //--- Retrieve data from file
         int cnt=0;
         while(Wininet::InternetReadFile(httprequest,ch,512,cnt))
           {
            //e=kernel32::GetLastError();
            if(cnt<=0)
               break;
            temp=temp+CharArrayToString(ch,0,cnt);
           }
         //--- Store result
         content=temp;
        }
     }

//--- Close connection
   if(httprequest>0)
      InternetCloseHandle(httprequest);
   if(httpopen>0)
      InternetCloseHandle(httpopen);

//--- Get out and return error code
   return(e);
  }
```

EDIT:

I found something interesting that may help:

I replaced the previous code and tried to use the inbuilt mql4 web request function

```
    //--- Call WebRequest function
    string method = "GET";
    string headers = "";
    int timeout = 5000; // Timeout in milliseconds (adjust as needed)
    char data[]; // No data to send
    char result[4096]; // Fixed-size array to hold response (adjust as needed)
    string result_headers;
    
    int request = WebRequest(method, url, headers, timeout, data, result, result_headers);
    
    // Check for successful request
    if (request == 200) {
        // Copy result to content string
        content = CharArrayToString(result);

        Print("Data collected");
    } else {
        // Handle error (you may want to add more error handling)
        Print("Error: Web request failed with code ", request);
    }

    return request;
```

I got these error pops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGziz.png)

and funny thing is I added these URLs in the experts tab of the mt4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNt12.png)

Comment: Are you sure that your problem lies with your program?  The description suggests it's more likely to be a problem with the configuration of your systems and/or network, in which case, it's outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes its a problem that looks in par with the program as adding the same links on the experts tab its rejecting it throwing an error

Comment: Also if its an issue with the system or network then maybe somebody can provide guidance regarding it as well as there maybe people around here from the system admin side as well